# Sharepoint Designer 2010 - Reusable Workflow - Content Type Document - Name of Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am new in Sharepoint Platform, i have developed a **reusable workflow** on **Document** content type. The workflow is very easy, only send a email to "Document Owner". This workflow is prepared to apply on retention policy when a document has not been updated in three months.

In the body, i want specify the name of "Document Library" where the document is allocated, but i don´t find a variable who say me this value.

Please, could you help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get list / library name 
[image]